# Input shifted in pygame and adafruit-touchscreen

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame, raspberry-pi, touchscreen

I am facing an issue with the input into pygame using the following hardware:

- Raspberry Pi 1 B
- [Adafruit 5" Touchscreen](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-5-800x480-tft-hdmi-monitor-touchscreen-backpack/overview) connected via HDMI and Touch Input via USB

the Touchscreen is set up according to the howto on the [adafruit website](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-5-800x480-tft-hdmi-monitor-touchscreen-backpack/raspberry-pi-config) (fixing resolution in /boot/config.txt to 800x480px).

It is all working perfect in the userinterface in raspbian. But as soon as i start my pygame application, I experience strange behaviour. The application is working perfectly well on a normal pc.
It seems like the video resolution is correct, but one of the touchscreen is slightly higher.

I am calling pygame with:

```
self._display_surf = pygame.display.set_mode([800,480], pygame.FULLSCREEN)
self._display_surf.fill(COLOR_BG)
pygame.display.update()
```

The issue I am facing is that if I slide over the screen, the mouse pointer is "overtaking" me. I made a [little video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0f6kvqbjyt488wu/Wasischlos%20muus.mp4?dl=0) for better understanding.

I already printed a list with

```
pygame.display.list_modes(16)
```

where I end with

```
[(1600, 1200), (1280, 1024), (1024, 1024), (1280, 960), (1152, 864), (1024, 768), (800, 600), (768, 576), (800, 480), (640, 480)]
```

But I have no idea where these come from. I cannot set different resolutions for touch input and screen, am I right?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was produced by calling the program via ssh. Calling the program in a local shell solved the problem.